# How to write this in most efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array (N = 10^4) and I need to find a difference between each two of the entries( calculating a potential given the coordinates of the atoms)
Here is the code I am writing in pure python, but its really not effective, can anyone tell me how to speed it up? (using numpy or weave). Here x,y are arrays of coordinates of atoms(just simple 1D array)

```
def potential(r):
   U = 4.*(np.power(r,-12) - np.power(r,-6))
   return U
def total_energy(x):
   E = 0.
   #need to speed up this part
   for i in range(N-1):
     for j in range(i):
         E += potential(np.sqrt((x[i]-x[j])**2))  
return E
```

Comment: It sounds like you already know how to speed it up; have you tried numpy or weave?

Comment: Ahhh good old Lennard-Jones potential :D

Comment: Why is `i` going only to `N-1`? You will miss the last entry in this case (`N-1` is excluded). Will `x` always be 1D or does this need to generalize?

Comment: Also, how much memory do you have available?

Comment: Thank you, yes indeed it was my mistake. It should be range(N). The memory is not an issue. I just need to make the program work for 100 atoms, ~10000 iterations in reasonable time.

Answer (score 5):

first you can use array arithmetics:

```
def potential(r):
    return 4.*(r**(-12) - r**(-6))

def total_energy(x):
    E = 0.
    for i in range(N-1):
        E += potential(np.sqrt((x[i]-x[:i])**2)).sum()
    return E
```

or you can test the fully vectorized version:

```
def total_energy(x):
    b=np.diag(x).cumsum(1)-x
    return potential(abs(b[np.triu_indices_from(b,1)])).sum()
```

Comment: or even shorter `return sum( potential(np.sqrt((x[i]-x[:i])**2)).sum() for i in range(N-1))`

Comment: This assumes that `x` is 1D, while what the OP states this I believe he is likely describing a 2D array of coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend looking into [scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html). Using `pdist` in particular computes all pairwise distances of an array.

I am assuming that you have an array that is of shape (Nx3), thus we need to slightly change your code:

```
def potential(r):
       U = 4.*(np.power(r,-12) - np.power(r,-6))
       return U
def total_energy(x):
   E = 0.
   #need to speed up this part
   for i in range(N):                                    #To N here
     for j in range(i):
         E += potential(np.sqrt(np.sum((x[i]-x[j])**2))) #Add sum here
   return E
```

Now lets rewrite this using spatial:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as sd


def scipy_LJ(arr, sigma=None):
    """
    Computes the Lennard-Jones potential for an array (M x N) of M points
    in N dimensional space. Usage of a sigma parameter is optional.
    """

    if len(arr.shape)==1:
        arr = arr[:,None]

    r = sd.pdist(arr)

    if sigma==None:
        np.power(r, -6, out=r)
        return np.sum(r**2 - r)*4

    else:
       r *= sigma
       np.power(r, -6, out=r)
       return np.sum(r**2 - r)*4
```

Lets run some tests:

```
N = 1000
points = np.random.rand(N,3)+0.1

np.allclose(total_energy(points), scipy_LJ(points))
Out[43]: True

%timeit total_energy(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 13.6 s per loop

%timeit scipy_LJ(points)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.3 ms per loop
```

Now it is ~500 times faster!

```
N = 10000
points = np.random.rand(N,3)+0.1

%timeit scipy_LJ(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.05 s per loop
```

This used ~2GB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final answer with some timing

0) The Plain version (Really slow)

```
In [16]: %timeit total_energy(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 14.9 s per loop
```

1) SciPy version

```
In [9]: %timeit scipy_LJ(points)
10 loops, best of 3: 44 ms per loop
```

1-2) Numpy version

```
 %timeit sum( potential(np.sqrt((x[i]-x[:i])**2 + (y[i]-y[:i])**2 + (z[i] - z[:i])**2)).sum() for i in range(N-1))
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop
```

2) Insanely fast Fortran version (! - means comment)

```
    subroutine EnergyForces(Pos, PEnergy, Dim, NAtom)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: Dim, NAtom
    real(8), intent(in), dimension(0:NAtom-1, 0:Dim-1) :: Pos
!    real(8), intent(in) :: L
    real(8), intent(out) :: PEnergy
    real(8), dimension(Dim) :: rij, Posi
    real(8) :: d2, id2, id6, id12
    real(8) :: rc2, Shift
    integer :: i, j
    PEnergy = 0.
    do i = 0, NAtom - 1
        !store Pos(i,:) in a temporary array for faster access in j loop
        Posi = Pos(i,:)
        do j = i + 1, NAtom - 1
            rij = Pos(j,:) - Posi
!            rij = rij - L * dnint(rij / L)
            !compute only the squared distance and compare to squared cut
            d2 = sum(rij * rij)
            id2 = 1. / d2            !inverse squared distance
            id6 = id2 * id2 * id2    !inverse sixth distance
            id12 = id6 * id6         !inverse twelvth distance
            PEnergy = PEnergy + 4. * (id12 - id6)
      enddo
    enddo
end subroutine
```

after calling it

```
In [14]: %timeit ljlib.energyforces(points.transpose(), 3, N)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61 us per loop
```

3) Conclusion Fortran is 1000 times faster than scipy and 3000 times faster than numpy, and millions times faster than the pure python. That is because the Scipy version creates a matrix of differences and then analyzes it, whereas the Fortran version does everything on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Here is what I have found.

1. The shortest version

   ```
   return sum( potential(np.sqrt((x[i]-x[:i])**2)).sum() for i in range(N-1))
   ```
2. The scipy version is also good.
3. The fastest version one may consider is to use the f2py program, i.e write the bottleneck slow part in pure Fortran(which is insanely fast), compile it and then plug it into your  python code as a library
   For example I have:
   program_lj.f90

*$gfortran -c program_lj.f90*

If one defines all the types explicitly in fortran program we are good to go.

*$f2py -c -m program_lj program_lj.f90*

After compilation the only thing left would be to call the program from python.
in python program:

```
import program_lj
result = program_lj.subroutine_in_program(parameters)
```

In case you need a more general reference please refer to wonderful [webpage](http://www.engr.ucsb.edu/~shell/che210d/assignments.html).

Comment: Would you mind timing all three programs? In principle there really should not be much difference between the scipy and fortran routines since scipy distance calls an optimized distance routine in a low level language.